# How to set default icon as an image adn remove folder icon in jstree?

Tags: jstree

currently in jstree, default icon is folder icon. How to set a new icon as default icon in jstree?

Answer (score 0):

Add the types plugin to the jstree and in types set the default icon in the default property:

```
"plugins": ["types"]
"types": {
    "default: {
        "icon": //new default icon here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `types` plugin as the other answer suggests. What I usually do however, to just replace these two files for a quicker solution:

```
32px.png
40px.png
```

Of course, the caveat is that this will change ALL icons from the new theme, not just the folder icon. These files are usually located in your same folder as your `jstree.min.css` file. The new icon is found bundled along with css in your themes folder. `jstree` actually embeds one of these two pngs (depending on the responsive state) on the displayed tree view.